# Adicionar classe Dinamicamente

Tags: jquery

Possuo um carousel onde os botões `prev` e `next` são gerados pelo plugin.

O problema é mesmo tentando adicionar uma classe com o método tradicional 
`$(".owl-prev").addClass("theme-color");` o mesmo não se aplica pois a `div` ainda não foi gerada.

Usando a função `on` também não funcionou:

```
$("#owl-main-banner").on("load", function(){
    $(".owl-prev").addClass("theme-color");
});
```

Comment: O plugin não tem um callback quando o deploy fôr feito? Qual é o plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Tu pode usar o método [`$.done`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) do `jQuery`. Quando o *plugin* for gerado ai sim você chama o seu `addClass()`.

Exemplo:

```
var dfd = $.Deferred();
dfd.done( [ fn1, fn2 ], fn3, [ fn2, fn1 ] )
```

Onde fn's são funções.

Estas serão executadas em ordem de adição.

Nota:

Se o `.done()` não funcionar, tente [$.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/).

Answer (score 1):

Pela classe utilizada no trecho do seu código, suponho que você esteja utilizando o plugin Owl Carousel, eu também o utilizo. Isso que você está tentando fazer pode facilmente ser alcançado o callback `afterInit` do próprio plugin.

Você vai querer dar uma olhada na documentação do [Owl Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/index.html) especialmente na seção 2 - **Callbacks**

Vou deixar aqui a solução, mas preparei um [demo](http://codepen.io/monecchi/pen/wazGdv) pra você ver o resultado.

CSS

```
/* Custom class for the nav - Classe customizada para navegação */
.theme-color {
  color: #fff;
  background: #3ABC4B !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

// Inicializa o plugin e define algumas variáveis de customização
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
  navigation: true,
  navigationText : false,
  navigationText : ["<",">"], 
  pagination:  false, // Esconde a navegação com "dots"
  afterInit : attachEvent // Após a inicialização, inclui um novo evento
});
// Com essa função abaixo encontramos o elemento pela classe e adicionamos
// a classe customizada, poderia ser qualquer outra função que você
// decidisse criar, bastaria chamar essa função na variável 
// `afterInit :` quando fosse inicializar o plugin
function attachEvent(elem){
 elem.parent().find('.owl-prev').addClass('theme-color')
 };

});
```

[demo](http://codepen.io/monecchi/pen/wazGdv)

Espero que consiga atingir o resultado esperado, boa sorte!